# Defining a function which returns a function pointer which also returns a function pointer without typedefs

Tags: c, function, function-pointers

I am trying to really understand function pointers without using `typedef` but cannot seem to get this. I do not understand what signature is needed to convey that I return a pointer to a pointer to a function.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void odd()  { printf("odd!\n");  }
void even() { printf("even!\n"); }

void (*get_pfn(int i))()
{
    return i % 2 == 0 ? &even : &odd;
}

__SIGNATURE__
{
    return &get_pfn;
}

int main()
{
    get_pfn_pfn()(1)();
    get_pfn_pfn()(2)();
    return 0;
}
```

To make this work, what does `__SIGNATURE__` have to be?

Comment: Good question - now don't ever do this again. :)

Comment: [use cdecl](https://cdecl.org/?q=declare+get_pfn+as+function+%28void%29+returning+pointer+to+function+%28int%29+returning+pointer+to+function+%28int%29+returning+void)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It has to return a function pointer to a function that takes an `int` and returns a function pointer:

```
void (*(*get_pfn_pfn(void))(int))(void) {
    return &get_pfn;
}
```

more lines:

```
void (*
        (*
             get_pfn_pfn(void)  // this is our function
        )(int i) // this is get_pfn(int)
     )(void)  // this is odd() or even()
{
    return &get_pfn;
}
```

The `void`s can be omitted, in which case the function pointer points to a function that takes unknown number of parameters. Which is not what you want. To declare a function pointer to a function that takes no arguments, you should add `void` inside function parameter list. The same way it's best to change `get_pfn` to `void (*get_pfn(int i))(void)`. For example try calling from `get_pfn(1)("some arg", "some other arg");`. A C compiler will not give a warning, as empty `()` denote *unknown* arguments. To say that function takes no arguments, you have to `(void)`.

For many the sequences of braces, especially `))(`, in function pointers are hard to parse. That's why many prefer typedefs for function pointers or types:

```
typedef void get_pfn_func_t(void);    
get_pfn_func_t *get_pfn(int i) {
    return i % 2 == 0 ? &even : &odd;
}

typedef get_pfn_func_t *get_pfn_pfn_func_t(int i);
get_pfn_pfn_func_t *get_pfn_pfn(void) {
    return &get_pfn;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much Kamil!! I like that broken down/visualized tree like view, it helped make it a lot more understandable :) !!

Comment: @Jas You may like it but I don't think it is recommended to write code in this manner.

Comment: I wish there was a website that had a GUI representation of a function pointer, let you move various components around, etc. Something like https://nsdateformatter.com

Answer (score 7):

The return type of the function `get_pfn` is -

```
void (*) ();
```

So type of `&get_pfn` is -

```
void (*(*)(int))()
```

Now, this function returns this type, hence its signature will be -

```
void (*(*(foo)())(int))()
```

You can verify this by typing this in [cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org/?q=void+%28*%28*%28foo%29%28%29%29%28int%29%29%28%29)

Comment: Thank you very much Ajay! Your explanation breaking down the steps helped me understand it more easily, but unfortunately the signature did not work sorry :(

Comment: @Jas, sorry I messed up the order of the `(int)`. I thought your odd even functions take a param int. I will correct it.

Answer (score 7):

Function pointers without a `typedef` can be tricky to work with.  To figure them out, you work from the inside out.

So let's break down exactly how we come up with the correct function signature.

`get_pfn_pfn` is a function:

```
get_pfn_pfn()
```

Which takes no parameters:

```
get_pfn_pfn(void)
```

And returns a pointer:

```
*get_pfn_pfn(void)
```

To a function:

```
(*get_pfn_pfn(void))()
```

Which takes an `int` parameter:

```
(*get_pfn_pfn(void))(int)
```

And returns a pointer:

```
*(*get_pfn_pfn(void))(int)
```

To a function:

```
(*(*get_pfn_pfn(void))(int))()
```

Which takes no parameters:

```
(*(*get_pfn_pfn(void))(int))(void)
```

And returns nothing (i.e. `void`):

```
void (*(*get_pfn_pfn(void))(int))(void)
```

---

Of course, using `typedef`'s simplifies this greatly.

First the type for `even` and `odd`:

```
typedef void (*func1)(void);
```

Which we can then apply to `get_pfn`:

```
func1 get_pfn(int) { ... }
```

Then the type for this function:

```
typedef func1 (*func2)(int);
```

Which we can apply to `get_pfn_pfn`:

```
func2 get_pfn_pfn(void) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

it's this way:

```
void (*(*get_pfn_pfn(void))(int))()
```

Comment: The other answers explain it in a better way.